# Best way to abstract over DU cases in F#?

Tags: f#

Suppose I have a DU like this:

```ml
type Fruit = 
  | Apple of int
  | Banana of string
  | Cherry of int * string
```

Now, I want to talk about the *cases of* the DU (not concrete *items in* the DU):

```ml
[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
type FruitType = 
  | Apple
  | Banana
  | Cherry

module FruitType = 
  
  let ofFruit =
    function
    | Apple _ -> FruitType.Apple
    | Banana _ -> FruitType.Banana
    | Cherry _ -> FruitType.Cherry

type FruitSaladRecipe = 
  {
    FruitsRequired : Set<FruitType>
  }
```

As you can see, there is some code duplication here: every case of `Fruit` has an equivalent case in `FruitType`, and vice-versa.

Is there a more elegant way to write this?

*Bonus points for not using reflection, this should be possible at compile-time.*

---

This problem has come up a few times for me, but I will try to give a more concrete example.

Let's say you were building a form designer where the user can add custom elements like:

- Drop downs
- Text inputs
- Sliders

In the menu for creating a new element, the first stage might be to pick a `FormElementType`:

```ml
[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
type FormElementType = 
  | DropDown
  | TextInput
  | Slider

let! chooseFormElementType : UserInteraction<FormElementType> = ...
```

After choosing a `FormElementType`, the user will design an actual `FormElement`:

```ml
type FormElement = 
  | DropDown of string list
  | TextInput of string option
  | Slider of int * int

let createFormElement formElementType : UserInteraction<FormElement> = 
  match formElementType with
  | FormElementType.DropDown -> 
    createDropDown
  | FormElementType.TextInput -> 
    createTextInput
  | FormElementType.Slider -> 
    createSlider
```

And then the new element can be added to a collection:

```ml
let form = Form.append formElement form
```

Comment: I get what you're asking and I don't think there is any clever way to do this, but I think the question would be a lot more informative if you described your actual use case for this, rather than apples & bananas. I think that would give more information about the trade-offs of different approaches, which is not really apparent with artificial example.

Comment: I suspect that if you have ended up in a situation where you need the union cases without their data it might be that the discriminated union should not exist in the first place. Would it be possible to restructure your domain models so that you would replace Fruit with FruitType and in places where you use Fruit you would use something else?

Comment: @TomasPetricek that's fair; I have tried to add an example.

Comment: @hvester I tried to make the example one where both types are required.

Comment: @sdgfsdh In the form designer example I think it makes sense to have separate types. I don't think the duplication is a problem, though having to use RequireQualifiedAccess might feel annoying. It might even be good that one-to-one mapping between FormElement and FormElementType is not enforced, for example if you want to have mandatory "submit" button in the end of the form that you want to have in FormElement, but it should not be available for the user to create.

Comment: @hvester yes my conclusion is that it is best just to live with it. This hits on the more generalized lack of F# features for compile-time functions from types to types.